# How do I join multiple tables and get a certain column(repeated in all tables with different values) into a single target table with one column

Tags: informatica, informatica-powercenter

So basically I have different tables with `player_name` present in all of them, now I want the names of all the players distinctly.
for ex, I have three tables T20, ODI and Test, which have some `player_names` as repeat and some `player_names` as different, now I want to build a database of player names and assign them with some ID, for which I want all of the players.
Please direct me to another question if you've seen another one which solves my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

can you pls -

1. create a SQ with below SQL( this gives distinct player names) -

```
select distinct player_name from Test union 
select distinct player_name from ODI union 
select distinct player_name from T20
```

2. Add seq gen to generate ID
3. Add #1 and #2 into an exp transformation and then flow them into a target.
4. Add other columns as needed.

Comment: How will I generate sql query for a flat file?

Comment: you mentioned you have tables. If they are files - then you need to create 3 separate Source Qualifier, use UNION to UNION all data and then use a sorter (distinct ) to get distinct player names.

Comment: yeah that was on me, should have specified. Thanks for the help though, I'll go ahead and give it a try!